# Pasar una variable de jQuery a un div de HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Buenas tengo el siguiente código de un árbol de navidad en el que tengo que hacer que caigan unas bolas de colores dentro del espacio verde del árbol en una imagen, hacer que se agite, que caigan las bolas y desaparezcan. Aparentemente todo marcha bien, pero al final del código donde tengo la función del shake, que caigan las bolas y desaparezcan no me corre porque las bolas las hice con una función y no con un div como tal. A ver quien puede ayudarme.

```
  var globo = $('<span/>').css({
        'border-radius': '50%',
        'width': '50px',
        'height': '50px',
        'background': randomColor,
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': '45%'

      }).animate({
        'top': top,
        'left': left
      })

      $('#arbolito').append(globo); 


   $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.mover').click(function(){
     $("#arbolito").effect("shake");
   window.setTimeout(function(){
   $(document.querySelectorAll("globo")).animate({
      marginTop:'355px',
    },250);
   $(document.querySelectorAll("globo")).fadeOut(200);
    },210);
   window.setTimeout(function(){
 $(document.querySelectorAll("globo")).remove();
    },1100);

   });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Hola tu problema parece ser que está aquí:

```
document.querySelectorAll("globo")
```

globo es un `<span>` que estas añadiendo al `#arbolito` y no un `HTML TAG <globo>`, al hacer querySelectorAll estas buscando los elementos que tengan X etiqueta html y no la variable globo que usas en javascript. Añadiendo la clase globo al span, puedes obtener todos los span con la clase globo.

Por ende tu función quedaría tal que:

```
  var globo = $('<span/>').css({
        'border-radius': '50%',
        'width': '50px',
        'height': '50px',
        'background': randomColor,
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': '45%'

      }).animate({
        'top': top,
        'left': left
      }).addClass('globo');

      $('#arbolito').append(globo); 


   $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.mover').click(function(){

       $("#arbolito").effect("shake");
       window.setTimeout(function(){

         $(document.querySelectorAll("span.globo")).animate({
           marginTop:'355px',
         },250);

         $(document.querySelectorAll("span.globo")).fadeOut(200);
         },210);

         window.setTimeout(function(){
            $(document.querySelectorAll("span.globo")).remove();
         },1100);

   });
```

[Documentacion QuerySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)